# show "show more" button instead of a vertical scrollbar in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed height div that contains some html content. When this height is overflowed, I don't want the scrollbar to appear, but instead a push button at the bottom of the div. And only when you push this button, all the content should be shown and obviously the scrollbar will be shown automatically. I understand that there is a property called "overflow" and you can use "scroll" value but I don't need the scrollbars until the user press the push button. Note, that there should be no button if the overflow doesn't happen.

```
---------------div starts-----------------
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT    

    [SHOW MORE BUTTON ]

---------------div ends-----------------
```

How would you implement this without jquery? How do you sense with javascript that the content will overflow?

Comment: You should first attempt what your asking for,  and present your question with what you've tried and specifically what your stuck on.  Also your question leave to many unknown  factors for anyone to give an accurate answer. There are many javascript library's,  as well as pure css option that might work for you.

Comment: @DirtyRedz I have no idea on how to implement it, that's why I am asking. I thought the question was clear, I just want a "SHOW MORE" button on the bottom of the div, there is an ASCII picture also.

Comment: What DirtyRedz is saying is that you'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you're asking a specific problem. Your question is very open-ended; there are many different ways to implement what you are asking. In fact, a quick web search will reveal quite many.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achive this using css only (using `checkbox` and `:checked` state).

Let me know if something is not clear.

Note: `max-height:500px;` is just an example. If the content suppose to be higher, play with this value.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

label:after {
  content: "more";
}

input:checked~label:after {
  content: "less";
}

.inner {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 100px;
}

input:checked+.inner {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="readmore" />
  <div class="inner">
    CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
  </div>
  <label for="readmore">Read </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow man, you didn't post code, its a piece of art. Amazingly simple. While it answers the question completely I can not use it because I have to use javascript to access that "more content" from database, so 100% with CSS is not suitable for me. But maybe somebody else will post any other idea. Thank you very much for these tips, my learning never stops.

Comment: Thank you! It's mean a lot to me to know that I helped to someone. About your comment: `access that "more content" from database` what do you mean? The `more content` text is come from the database? Can you post the **exactly** html that returns from the database?

Comment: This is pretty cool. The only thing is that "Read more" is still visible even when the content is short and does not overflow. I'm after a solution that only shows "Read more" when its required.

Comment: Sure. A tiny piece of javascript can be involved in order to solve this issue.