# How to add transition effect onclick in navigation menu w3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a smooth transition onclick  with javascript on navigation menu (responsive in mobile with click hamburger button). The navigation based on W3. [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown).
But, why i can't click the menu, and how to make smooth transition onclick, use new javascript or only add some css to make transition?

Here's my code, there i just replaced the javascript from w3.

```js
//my javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $div = $(this).next('.responsive');
      $(".responsive").not($div).slideUp();
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $div.slideUp();
        }  else {
           $div.slideDown();
        }
    });
    $(document).click(function(e){
        var p = $(e.target).closest('.topnav').length
        if (!p) {
              $(".responsive").slideUp();
        }
    });   
});

//here is javascript by w3
// function myFunction() {
//     var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
//     if (x.className === "topnav") {
//       x.className += " responsive";
//     } else {
//       x.className = "topnav";
//     }
//   }
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="function()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It will help to see the html too. Or, even better, make the snippet works so we could **see** the problem.

Comment: Please included html code into your snippet, or we can't seen your problem then solve your problem.

Comment: Edited, I just adding the html & css to..

Comment: The html doesn't contain `.responsive`..

Comment: In css @media .topnav.responsive

Comment: Without having it in the html it's irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, how about javascript from w3 in bottom, there have all the contain. But, it's not have transition. can you help me to add transition with that. I just try add transition effect in css but not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon").click(function(e) {
        var $div = $(this).parent();
        if ($div.hasClass('open')) {
            $div.animate({height: "48px"}, undefined, undefined, function() { $(this).removeClass('open responsive') });
        }  else {
            $div.animate({height: "236px"}, undefined, undefined, function() { $(this).css({'height': 'auto'}); });
            $div.addClass('open responsive');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
    <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  /* display: none; */
  height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    height: 130px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive { display: block; position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Notes:-

- Had to use `.animate()` instead of `.slidUp()` and `.slidDown()` as `.slidUp()` will at the end will make the element hidden, which we don't want in this case.
- Because of that one down side of solving it in this way is, that we have fix the height in px for open and close state..
- So it better be done with using `css`, and in JS we simply should add that `css` class

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using css only by animating `max-height` similar to what I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38682942/863110)

Basically the default style is

```css
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all .15s ease;
```

and the hover

```css
max-height: 100px; /* the height of the shortest dropdown at least */
```

**Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      /* display: none; */
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      transition: all .15s ease;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      /* display: block; */
      max-height: 100px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav a:not(:first-child),
      .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
      }
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
    <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/pisiwib/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I mean the transition for the icon in the navigation not the dropdown in the navigation.

Comment: `transition for the icon` What the transition does? I'm curious to see what have you got. Can you show me in jsbin or jsfiddle?